# Should a class have a getter or just public field for cached data?

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a class that fetches something from Internet, then returns it to the user, and it is also cached in one of the class fields. What is considered good practice: to have a `class.get_data()` that returns `class.__data__.copy()`, or to have data as a public member?

Comment: make `data` a descriptor.

Comment: ... in other words, use the [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator.

Comment: @ZeroPiraeus so it is exactly the case for it?

Comment: Yes, attributes which are expensive to obtain are the primary use case for properties.